# PHP if statement not responding correctly

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm having an issue with the PHP if statement, I think it will be fairly easy but I just can't figure it out.

So when I click the link tag on the first webpage, I will go to "editalbum.php" together with the data. However if I would like to use the albumgenre_dnb value in an if statement it does not work (see part 2 for the if statement). Also I am sure that these values are being put trough as they appear in the url namely:

> (/Declassified%20Recordings/php/custom/albums/change/editalbum.php?ids=1%20&names=NFS%20&releasedate=18/10/1993%20&%20artists=Sin%20wave,%20Nerexo%20&thumbnail=Testpath/thm%20&banner=testpahtbanner/thm%20&**albumgenre_dnb=DNB**%20&albumgenre_dubstep=DUBSTEP%20&albumgenre_EDM=EDM%20&albumgenre_trap=TRAP%20&%20albumgenre_chill=CHILL%20&mediafirelinks=/nerexoawesome%20&dropboxlinks=/test.com/dropbox)

So in fact with the current if statement it should echo "Drum and Bass" but it doesn't for some reason.

Aside from that, if I echo just the variable that I made I get "DNB" so the problem lies in the if statement...

*Thank you so much for your help!*

**Part 1 (link tag)**

```
<a href='editalbum.php?
ids=$id &
names=$name &
releasedate=$releasedate & 
artists=$artists &
thumbnail=$thumbnail &
banner=$banner &
albumgenre_dnb=$albumgenre_dnb &
albumgenre_dubstep=$albumgenre_dubstep &
albumgenre_EDM=$albumgenre_EDM &
albumgenre_trap=$albumgenre_trap & 
albumgenre_chill=$albumgenre_chill &
mediafirelinks=$mediafire &
dropboxlinks=$dropbox'>$id
</a>
```

**Part 2 (if statement)**

```
<?php 

    $dnb = $_REQUEST ['albumgenre_dnb'];

    if ($dnb != "") {
        echo "Drum and bass";
    }

    else {}

?>
```

Comment: Your code example worked for me. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with what you posted.

Comment: **Part 2** is in `editalbum.php`, right?

Comment: Hello guys, because I don't have enough points or so I cant anwser my own questions, but I found that variables without a value that were put through are considered as " " (a space) and not "" like I thought. So the answer is just putting a space between the double qoutes, sorry! (and thanks ofcourse!!)

Comment: Have you `var_dump`ed `$_REQUEST` to see what it contains? Theoretically, I think it can be empty, based on settings in PHP.ini: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value includes a space:

```
albumgenre_dnb=DNB%20
```

`%20` means a space. That is because of the spaces you have before the ampersands. So the value of the parameter is `DNB<space>`. For empty values, it is just the space and not a completely empty string, so `$dnb != ''` will always return true, also if `$albumgenre_dnb` was empty.

Now, this doesn't really match your example, because you test for a `not empty` string, so you should always get the text "Drum and bass" in the output. Could it be that you made a mistake in your example?

Comment: Well with this album yes, but I have others who have that value "empty", but like you said the value is a space :) I found it but I can't answer my own questions because the lack of points or something :) Thanks!

Comment: The problem is in the PHPcode: `albumgenre_dnb=$albumgenre_dnb &` as you can see, there is a space after the variable and before the `&`. This space also ends up in your url as part of the value. As a matter of fact, I think you should be lucky that it also doesn't contain returns. You shouldn't have any whitespace in your url at all. So, it's not because empty values are 'always' spaces. It's a specific error in your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$dnb = $_REQUEST ['albumgenre_dnb'];

if (strlen($dnb)>0) {
    echo "Drum and bass";
}

else {}
```

also you can assing your $dnb to $_GET

```
$dnb = $_GET ['albumgenre_dnb'];
```

Note: IF your part 2 is in your like page you should control it isset:

```
if(isset($_GET ['albumgenre_dnb'])){
    $dnb = $_REQUEST ['albumgenre_dnb'];

    if (strlen($dnb)>0) {
        echo "Drum and bass";
    }

    else {}

}
```